# Change Ionic modal template when opened/selected

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that opens a modal window.
How can I change the templateUrl value when the modal window is opened?

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal-details.html', {
   scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up',
    hardwareBackButtonClose: true
}).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
});
```

// Open window here..

```
$scope.openModal = function(selected){

   // How can I change the templateUrl based on the selected value?


    $scope.data.selected = selected;
```

Comment: What about having a `ng-include` inside the `modal-details.html` which will change based on the selected value on open?

Comment: How do I do that.. Can you give me some more info.